# How can jenkins use maven deploy url?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I use Jenkins to build  and deploy my java application with maven deploy.
when maven deploy zip/war to nexus then  use "Publisher over ssh" to call a command on remote server.

How can i get the deploy url and pass to the command? like ./command.sh $Deploy_Url

Comment: or other way ,when publisher over ssh work on transfer file to remote server . but how can i get the filename

Comment: You know the groupId/artifactId plus version?

Comment: I just wonder if the maven plugin would put some context params into jenkins， then i can use in the next step。

Comment: About which maven plugin are you talking about?

Comment: maven deploy。and jenkins publish over ssh